# Documenting member functions with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have something like this:

```
/**
Diese Klasse bla bla...
@constructor 
**/
my.namespace.ClassA = function(type)
{
   /**
   This function does something
   **/
   this.doSomething = function(param){
   }
}
```

The class will get listed in the generated documentation. The function won't. Is there a way to tell JSDoc (3) that this is a member function of the class `ClassA`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSDoc needs some additional information to recognize the function as member function:

```
/**
  * Diese Klasse bla bla...
  * @constructor 
*/
my.namespace.ClassA = function(type)
{
   /**
    * This function does something
    * @function
    * @memberOf my.namespace.ClassA
   */
   this.doSomething = function(param){
   }
}
```

Comment: Now if i use it that way. It will display `<static>` in front of the function body. But it's not a static function. If i use "@instance" to tell jsdoc that this is an instance function it will disappear again. Any Idea?

Comment: Does it help if you change it to `@memberOf my.namespace.ClassA.prototype`?

Comment: No, it still disappears

Comment: For anyone who might be wondering this, using *only* the `@instance` tag does the trick.

Comment: Another problem could be the memberOf instead memberof (all lowercase). I had a problem with that in the past.

Answer (score 12):

Try this!

```
/**
  * Diese Klasse bla bla...
  * @constructor 
*/
my.namespace.ClassA = function(type)
{
   /**
    * This function does something
    * @function doSomething
    * @memberOf my.namespace.ClassA#
   */
   this.doSomething = function(param){
   };
};
```

JSDoc seems quite clunky in this area :/ The key is to specify both memberof and the name of the function. [See also](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsdoc-users/L5McS4jvf78).

Comment: Thanks, the _only_ working solution I found in _hours_. Pointed me in the right direction. _Clunky_ does not make enough justice to this kind of a mess ...

Comment: I've been scratching my head for hours now. This fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly describe the function using full namepath. There are 3 types of namepath syntaxes to describe functions:

```
Person#say  // the instance method named "say."
Person.say  // the static method named "say."
Person~say  // the inner method named "say."
```

See details in [this page](https://jsdoc.app/about-namepaths.html).